# Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused error

Tags: android, gradle

when I try to create new module with `Android SDK Build-tools` version `"24.0.2"`, below error occurs:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':audiowidget'.
   > Could not download support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/support-media-compat-24.2.0.aar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/support-media-compat-24.2.0.aar'.
            > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

the complete `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tabaneshahr.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

the `android SDK` is updated to the newest version of `Android SDK Build-tools` --> `24.0.2`
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: You have to update the Android Repository (the last group), not the tools or Android 7.0

Comment: it's updated to rev. 36 @GabrieleMariotti